# How to Create new Autoincrement Column in to Dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have a basic question in python

How to create Index Column with Auto Increment with 1 which is similar to X=X+1

```
Data['Index'] = Data['Index'] + 1 --> This line didn't worked for me
```

Comment: Did you try ``Data['Index'] += 1`? What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. If you want to have a new index auto-incrementing from 1:

```
df["new_index"] = df.index + 1
```

should work.

I think the problem you may have had is calling your new column by the same name you are incrementing.

Comment: I am getting below error , My Index Value is DateTime , 

TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with DatetimeArray is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Comment: What do you want your new "index" to be, and what is the purpose of the old one? Are you trying to get to a date time shifted by a period, or an integer? What's the relationship between what you have now and your desired outcome?

Comment: I have a Dataframe which contains Date as a index and Price as one of the column , So My Actual requirement is i wanted the get the Highest Price of last 20 days from current date value of each row ,  I thought  to create three new columns that are "Current Date" , "Current Date - 20Days" and  "Current Row Index"  I trying to get the output using the code   Data.loc[Data['Current Date -20'][0] : Data['Current Date'][0].max()  ,  So here Instead of [0] I wanted to get the Current Row Index and make value Dynamic , I am using  Index Value which is Date Field for other purpose in my program

Comment: I am new to Python and i not sure if there is any other best way to get the result. Please let me know if there is any simplest way to achieve my output

Comment: `df["20_day_max"] = df["Price"].rolling("20 D").max()`
should give you what you want I think. Give it a try and let me know.